# Symfony: call form handleRequest but avoid entity persist

Tags: forms, symfony

I have an entity that models a search form and a form type, I use that form for searching purposes only and I don't want that entity to be modified in database, so, when I do this:

```
$formModelEntity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:SearchForm')
                      ->findOneBy(array('name' => 'the_model'));
$formModelForm = $this->createForm(new SearchFormType(), $formModelEntity, array('action' => $this->generateUrl('dosearch'), 'method' => 'POST'));
$formModelForm->handleRequest($request); //or ->submit($request);
if ($formModelForm->isValid())
{
     $formInstanceEntity->setFieldsFromModel($formModelEntity);
     $em->persist($formInstanceEntity);
     $em->flush();
}
```

The `$formModelEntity` changes are persisted to database, I want to avoid this but still want to take advantage of `handleRequest` ability to update the entity with all POST values (for read only purposes).

Is this possible?

Comment: As you can see I persist a different entity, but `$formModelEntity` is also persisted in database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In symfony, you only have to persist a new entity. If you update an existing entity found by your entity manager and then flush, your entity will be updated in database even if you didn't persist it.

Edit : you can detach an entity from the entity manager before flushing it using this line of code :

```
$em->detach($formModelEntity);
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know that. How can I avoid this? I need to persist a new entity which reads some data from a *read only* pre-existing entity

Comment: You could detach your entity from the entity manager before flushing it :

    $em->detach($formModelEntity);

Comment: Note `detach()` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

the method handleRequest Does not save the changes. it only updates the object within your method.

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
// just setup a fresh $task object (remove the dummy data)
$task = new Task();

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
    ->add('task', TextType::class)
    ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task'))
    ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    // ... perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

    return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
}

return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
));
```

}

the following snippet exists at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

and as you can see the entity is not persisted.

You're are probably adding a persist/flush and that's what's causing the entities to be updated.

Comment: I actually do `persist` of another entity and I need to do `flush` for that, but I don't persist the model entity (added some extra code)

Comment: Humm, so you want to persist Entity A that has a relationship with Entity B and yet you do not want to persist Entity B?

Comment: it does not relate, it only reads some of its attributes to set its own values, but there's not a direct relation

Comment: Try doing only `$em->flush($IWantOnlyThisToUpdate)`. Regular `$em->flush()` persists all updated object in it's memory

Comment: Good solution too, though I accepted jiboulex answer